# How to iterate two variables in bash script?

Tags: bash, shell, loops, for-loop, glob

I have these kind of files:

```
file6543_015.bam
subreadset_15.xml
file6543_024.bam
subreadset_24.xml
file6543_027.bam
subreadset_27.xml
```

I would like to run something like this:

```
for i in *bam && l in *xml
do
    my_script $i $l > output_file 
done
```

Because in my command the first `bam` file goes with the first `xml` file. For each combination bam/xml, that command will give a specific output file.

Comment: Is your list of files fixed? or how is the list generated?

Comment: The bam and xml files are generated via another command, done earlier. It gives necessarily one .bam file and its .xml file.

Comment: @Paillou : So that "other" command also establishes the association, which bam file "belongs to" which xml file? Usually, such associations are represented in bash by an associative array, but you did not show **how** the other command generates the two file lists. Maybe a good solution would involve change that command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this, using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) *arrays*:

```
bam=( *.bam )
xml=( *.xml )
for ((i=0; i<${#bam[@]}; i++)); do
    my_script "${bam[i]}" "${xml[i]}"
done
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you have way to uniquely name your output_file for each specific output,
here is one way:

```
#!/bin/bash
ls file*.bam | while read i
do
    CMD=`echo -n "my_script $i "`
    CMD="$CMD `echo $i | sed -e 's/file.*_0/subreadset_/' -e 's/.bam/.xml/'`"
    $CMD >> output_file
done
```

Comment: `ls file*.bam | while read i` is buggy. See [Why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). In addition to the issues discussed there, when `read` is used without clearing `IFS` and passing the `-r` argument, it both trims trailing whitespace and removes backslashes.

Comment: Beyond that, running `$CMD` doesn't work the way you expect for reasons described in [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050). In particular, it doesn't work for commands with pipes or quotes, so the code given in this answer _definitely_ doesn't function as-intended. (And the mechanisms by which one _can_ parse strings as commands commands are generally prone to security issues for the reasons described in [BashFAQ #48](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048), so the BashFAQ #50 practices should always be used instead).

Comment: Thanks Charles for the helpful feedback!